# SQL Server - Query String Greater Or Equal To

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I am attempting to optimise a query in my application that is causing problems when scaling my application.
The table contains two columns: FROM and TO which each contain values. Here is an example:

```
Row | From | To
1   | AA   | Z
2   | B    | C
3   | JA   | JZ
4   | JM   | JZ
```

The query is passed a name (JOHN) and should return a list of ranges from the table that could contain the name.

```
select * from Ranges where From <= 'JOHN' and To >= 'JOHN'
```

Using the table above this would result in rows 1 and 3 being returned.
The problem I am having is one of query consistency. 
All indexes are in place but if I search for JOHN the query returns in 20 milliseconds, whereas MARK returns in 250 milliseconds.
Looking at query analyzer shows me that JOHN is actually searching for more rows than MARK but I'm struggling to understand how or why MARK takes so long.
If the time difference was 20 - 40 milliseconds, I could live with that but 250 is so large a difference that the overall performance of my application is terrible.
Does anybody have any idea how I could narrow down why I get such variance in my queries OR a better way of storing and searching for string ranges (which could contains letters and numbers).

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT - One thing I forgot to mention was that the original table contains approximately 15 million rows (its actually postcodes).

Comment: `Using the table above this would result in rows 1 and 3 being returned` can you explain this result

Comment: Can you further explain how the example query logic is supposed to work? Can you also post the table schema, along with any indexes that may be on the table?